# Как заставить telegram-бота ожидать ответа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Впервые работаю с библиотекой telebot. Мне нужно заставить бота ожидать ответа от пользователя. Но обычный input() к сожалению не работает. Можно разве что только отправлять в консоль, и получать в телеграме, но мне так не нужно. Я хочу из телеграма, например, выводить вопрос от телеграм бота, и если ответ правильный или неправильный - вывести "Верно"/"Неверно" с переходом к следующему вопросу.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать в телеграм боте? Спасибо!

**Мой код:**

```
@bot.message_handler()


def func(message):
    rightanswer = 0
    wronganswer = 0
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо, начнём!')

    for key, value in dict.items():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, key)
        answer = input(key)
        if (answer == value):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Да')
            rightanswer += 1
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нет')
            wronganswer += 1
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Верных ответов {} неверных ответов {}'.format(rightanswer, wronganswer))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Для пользователя **garrythehotdog:**

```
dict = {'Cколько углов у квадрата?': '4', 'Сколько углов у треугольника?': '3', 'Лучший язык программирования для парсинга?': 'Python'}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    for key in dict.keys():
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, key)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, func)


def func(message):
    rightanswer = 0
    wronganswer = 0

    for value in dict.values():
        answer = message.text
        if (answer == value):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Да')
            rightanswer += 1
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нет')
            wronganswer += 1
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Верных ответов {} неверных ответов {}'.format(rightanswer, wronganswer))

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 2):

После отправки сообщения пользователя используйте метод `bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func)` который на ответ пользователя  вызовет функцию funс.

Comment: Я делаю как вы сказали, но когда перебираю в цикле ключи в словаре - сразу вываливает их все на экран, и не ждёт ввода. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: пример кода скиньте, должно все работать, если вы правильно выстоили логику

Comment: Я добавил код в пост. Подскажите, в чем проблема? Использую reply_to и register_next_step_handler, все равно ответа не ожидает, и все ключи в словаре сразу выводит. Что не так делаю? Спасибо.

Comment: Вы меня просили код скинуть - я скинул в шапку. Ну и, что не так в коде?

Answer (score 0):

Прочитать введенное пользователем сообщение можно через `message.text`.

Простенький пример кода:

```
if message.text == 'какой-то ответ':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верный ответ!')
    rightanswer += 1
```

Comment: А если я в цикле прохожусь по словарю? Если меняю input() на message.text -  бот мне вываливает все сообщения сразу. Как тогда делать, чтобы бот ожидал ответа?

Comment: @Slayer598 можете убрать переменную answer и реализовать ввод ответа как: if message.text == 'ваш ответ': Если это вам не подходит, то я возможно не правильно вас понял

Comment: Я пробую как вы говорите, бот все равно вываливает все сообщения и не ожидает ответа.